# CSS question - my before content element wont show up due to overflow property

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

```
import fetcher from '../utils/fetcher';
import useSWR from 'swr';

function FollowerList({ url }) {
  const { data, error } = useSWR(url, fetcher);
  if (error) {
    return <p>error</p>;
  }
  if (!data || data.length === 0) {
    return <p>No Followers Found</p>;
  }
  return (
    <div className="bg-base-300 p-[1.25rem] rounded-md relative before:content-['Followers'] before:absolute before:-top-6 before:left-0 before:bg-base-300 before:px-4 before:text-accent overflow-y-scroll space-y-4">
      {data.map((follower) => {
        return (
          <div key={follower.id} className='flex space-x-4'>
            <div className='avatar'>
              <div className='w-12 rounded-full'>
                <img src={follower.avatar_url} />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className='capitalize font-lato'>
              <h4 className='font-bold'>{follower.login}</h4>
              <a
                href={follower.html_url}
                target='_blank'
                rel='noreferrer'
                className='normal-case hover:text-accent transition-colors'
              >
                {follower.html_url}
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default FollowerList;
```

above is my JSX code, I know because of the overflow-y-scroll my before content won't show up. is there a way to solve it? I tried to wrap it with another div or so it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider removing the `overflow-y: scroll` property, since the element would never induce a scroll since the content of the element does not seem it would ever overflow with the code given:

```js
tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        accent: 'red',
        base: {
          300: 'skyblue',
        },
      },
    },
  },
};

const fetcher = null;
const useSWR = url => ({
  data: [
    {
      id: 'foo',
      avatar_url: 'https://picsum.photos/48/48',
      login: 'Foo',
      html_url: 'https://www.example.com/foo',
    },
    {
      id: 'bar',
      avatar_url: 'https://picsum.photos/48/48?',
      login: 'Bar',
      html_url: 'https://www.example.com/bar',
    },
  ],
  error: false,
});

function FollowerList({ url }) {
  const { data, error } = useSWR(url, fetcher);
  if (error) {
    return <p>error</p>;
  }
  if (!data || data.length === 0) {
    return <p>No Followers Found</p>;
  }
  return (
    <div className="bg-base-300 p-[1.25rem] rounded-md relative before:content-['Followers'] before:absolute before:-top-6 before:left-0 before:bg-base-300 before:px-4 before:text-accent space-y-4">
      {data.map((follower) => {
        return (
          <div key={follower.id} className='flex space-x-4'>
            <div className='avatar'>
              <div className='w-12 rounded-full'>
                <img src={follower.avatar_url} />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className='capitalize font-lato'>
              <h4 className='font-bold'>{follower.login}</h4>
              <a
                href={follower.html_url}
                target='_blank'
                rel='noreferrer'
                className='normal-case hover:text-accent transition-colors'
              >
                {follower.html_url}
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<FollowerList/>);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Otherwise, you could consider moving the `::before` pseudo-element outside the `overflow-y: scroll` element. At this point, you may as well have it as an element instead of a pseudo-element:

```js
tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        accent: 'red',
        base: {
          300: 'skyblue',
        },
      },
    },
  },
};

const fetcher = null;
const useSWR = url => ({
  data: [
    {
      id: 'foo',
      avatar_url: 'https://picsum.photos/48/48',
      login: 'Foo',
      html_url: 'https://www.example.com/foo',
    },
    {
      id: 'bar',
      avatar_url: 'https://picsum.photos/48/48?',
      login: 'Bar',
      html_url: 'https://www.example.com/bar',
    },
  ],
  error: false,
});

function FollowerList({ url }) {
  const { data, error } = useSWR(url, fetcher);
  if (error) {
    return <p>error</p>;
  }
  if (!data || data.length === 0) {
    return <p>No Followers Found</p>;
  }
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h2 className="bg-base-300 px-4 text-accent mb-4">
        Followers
      </h2>
      <div className="bg-base-300 p-[1.25rem] rounded-md overflow-y-scroll space-y-4">
        {data.map((follower) => {
          return (
            <div key={follower.id} className='flex space-x-4'>
              <div className='avatar'>
                <div className='w-12 rounded-full'>
                  <img src={follower.avatar_url} />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className='capitalize font-lato'>
                <h4 className='font-bold'>{follower.login}</h4>
                <a
                  href={follower.html_url}
                  target='_blank'
                  rel='noreferrer'
                  className='normal-case hover:text-accent transition-colors'
                >
                  {follower.html_url}
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<FollowerList/>);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```